# Solidity Point of _ statements

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I'm looking at a simple example for accepting payments in [Solidity](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11787/accepting-ethereum-on-a-website), I see they've set up a modifier which only allows the owner to to executue certain functions.

```
modifier onlyOwner {
    if(msg.sender != owner) throw;
    _;
}
```

I'm confused on the purpose of the _ statement.  What exactly is the purpose of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the _ is just a place holder for where the function should be [executed](https://www.bitdegree.org/learn/solidity-function-modifiers/)

Comment: Exactly, it's specifically made for function modifiers - there can also be multiple calls to the modified function (multiple "_"s), also see [this question on Ethereum](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/5861/are-underscores-in-modifiers-code-or-are-they-just-meant-to-look-cool).